# create a service always for every broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I observed a pattern where all `BroadcastReceiver` had a `Service` created along with it. I agree that long running process requires `service`.

Are there any benefits in creating a `service` for all `BroadcastReceiver` and use `BroadcastReceiver` just to receive a broadcast pass it to the `service` ?

Is it okay to run a non-complex operations/task in `BroadcastReceiver` itself ? Any disadvantages or any anti patterns?

Comment: well, normally tend to use broadcast for light operation within 10sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using BroadcastReceivers, it really depends on the amount of work that's needed to be done.

If the work is light enough **and** can be completed within 10 seconds, then it's alright to run it straight from the **onReceive()** method. For light work such as these, it makes less sense to start up a Service just to easily finish that work.

There's only 3 real dangers for doing work inside the BroadcastReceiver:

- Doing work in a background thread **might** cause the BroadcastReceiver to be killed before all work is done. Once the end of `onReceive()` is reached, the BroadcastReceiver's process will be considered a low-priority process, so it can potentially be killed if the system requires it. *Therefore, doing work in the background might cause your work to not finish properly which is quite dangerous if you're inserting data into a database.*
- Doing work on the Main Thread to avoid 
  reaching the end of `onReceive()`. I've seen developers do this to combat the previous issue, which causes performance problems due to potentially doing too much work on the Main Thread. I'm sure you know why this is a bad thing.
- Doing too much work and exceeding 10 seconds will cause the system to consider your app as not-responding.

Of course, you can actually request to extend the limit for background work a bit through the `goAsync()` method, but this isn't a method you should use instead of a Service.

So with those 3 dangers I mentioned, it makes sense why the popular solution for doing more work is to pass the work to a proper Service or JobScheduler.

So it's really up to you to decide which is best for your use case.

1. If the work is really light, there's no issues with doing the work in the BroadcastReceiver.
2. If the work is light but the data is important and can't be risked, then consider doing it in a Service.
3. If the work is heavy, definitely do it through a Service or schedule it as a job in the JobScheduler.

But honestly, my general advice is to use BroadcastReceivers sparingly. Only use them if it's necessary, since having too many registered BroadcastReceivers and services can affect your app's performance.

Comment: Thanks. Related question is "what is the cost - latency, resource consumption for creating android service ?"

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer in the comments, since there's a difference depending on if it's a background Service, foreground Service, and bound Service. It also makes a difference if it's a normal Service or a variant like IntentService. It's better for you to create a new question to ask this question.

Comment: @Jackey can you solve this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63350856/5359340